# generate only objectLayer of Entity Framework Model by edmgen tool

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, edmgen

How to generate only **objectLayer** by **edmgen tool**, without generating **csdl, ssdl and views** ?

> "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\edmgen.exe"
>   /mode:fullgeneration /c:"Data
>   Source=.\sqlexpress; Initial
>   Catalog=uqs; Integrated Security=SSPI"
>   /project:generateEntityModel
>   /entitycontainer:uqsEntities
>   /namespace:uqsModel /language:CSharp
>   /outobjectlayer:"D:/uqsObjectLayer.cs"

in this script I don't write location to write csdl, ssdl and views , but they are generated in **C:\Users\adminUser** in windows Vista and objectLayer generated to **D:/uqsObjectLayer.cs**. If I use **/mode:EntityClassGeneration**, `this option requires the /incsdl argument and either the /project argument or the /outobjectlayer  argument. The /language argument is optional.`

But I don't want use **csdl** file. As I understand, edmgen.tool can not create **objectlayer** without **csdl** file. Now is there alternate way or tool for generating **objectlayer** from db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mode:EntityClassGeneration doesn't generate CSDL; it *reads* it. You cannot generate source code without reading CSDL, ever (note, though, that the CSDL can be part of an EDMX file).